# child unittest class wont recognise parent member

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm running the following code, which implements a parent and child members of type `unittest.Testcase`

it seems like the parent's test members won't recognize the child's members, even though they should be run after the setup class (or am I wrong?)

```
import unittest

class all_object_runner():

    def __init__(self):

        self.lift=0


class Global_tests(unittest.TestCase):
    __test__ = False

    def test_lift_globaly(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.aor.lift >= 0)


class Test_loacl(Global_tests):

    __test__ = True

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.aor = all_object_runner()

    def test_if_lift_localy(self):
        corr=self.aor.lift
        self.assertTrue(corr>=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

why is this code failing:

```
File "....implement_all_tests.py", line 15, in test_lift_globaly
    self.assertTrue(self.aor.lift >= 0)
AttributeError: 'Global_tests' object has no attribute 'aor'
```

Comment: Why do you expect that `Global_tests` class has `aor` member?

Comment: I would like testlocal to run first its setup, then the parent tests and then its own tests

Comment: setup in child class doesn't have any effect on behavior of parent class.

Comment: the `setUpClass` should moved to class `Global_tests`, is it?